# Mythos Card Resolution During Setup

Tags: arkham-horror

When setting up for Arkham, you are instructed to draw a Mythos card in order to place the first gate and monster(s). 
Is it correct to resolve any headline that causes additional monsters to spawn? e.g. 2 monsters are released in the rivertown streets?

The reason I ask is that this occured in the last game we played and we were immediately on the back foot with two relatively weaker investigators 'trapped' by these monsters on the streets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you do as per the setup [rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/Support/Arkham_Horror_Rules_Lo-Res.pdf) (page 5):

```
14. DRAW AND RESOLVE MYTHOS CARD
Finally, the first player draws the top card of the mythos
deck and resolves it as described in the Mythos Phase
section of the rules.
...
After the mythos card has been completely resolved, the
first turn begins, starting with the first player.
```

If you are beginners, you may want to forgo #14 and only apply ongoing effects of the first mythos card, rather than the active effects (such as the one you encountered).

Comment: Also important to note that if a Rumour is drawn for the Mythos card during game setup, you should discard it and redraw until you draw a card that isn't a Rumour.